# Confluent Control Center will not start, continously rebalancing, spewing lock exceptions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I'm using confluent platform 3.2.0, kafka 0.10.2.

I've been running the confluent Control Center, and it was doing fine for about a week, but it's in some kind of unstable state now. The issue appears to originate from the kafka streams logic the Control Center uses internally.

I've encountered a number of errors and exceptions. I'm not sure what's related and what's cruft, but I'll paste what I see.

When I bounce brokers, I see many of these messages:

```
[2017-04-04 17:20:04,387] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/var/lib/kafka/_confluent-controlcenter-3-1-0-1-error-topic-3/00000000000000000000.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no larger than the base offset 0.}. deleting /var/lib/kafka/_confluent-controlcenter-3-1-0-1-error-topic-3/00000000000000000000.timeindex, /var/lib/kafka/_confluent-controlcenter-3-1-0-1-error-topic-3/00000000000000000000.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2017-04-04 17:20:04,387] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 0 in log _confluent-controlcenter-3-1-0-1-error-topic-3. (kafka.log.Log)
[2017-04-04 17:20:04,388] INFO Completed load of log _confluent-controlcenter-3-1-0-1-error-topic-3 with 1 log segments and log end offset 0 in 2 ms (kafka.log.Log)
```

When I bounce the control center, it will begin to start up, but then will continuously rebalance:

```
[2017-04-04 17:22:20,607] INFO tocheck=[Store{name=KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000107-store, rollup=false}, Store{name=KSTREAM-OUTERTHIS-0000000106-store, rollup=false}, Store{name=Group, rollup=true}, Store{name=MonitoringStream, rollup=true}, Store{name=TriggerActionsStore, rollup=false}, Store{name=MonitoringMessageAggregatorWindows, rollup=true}, Store{name=MonitoringTriggerStore, rollup=false}, Store{name=aggregatedTopicPartitionTableWindows, rollup=true}, Store{name=MonitoringVerifierStore, rollup=false}, Store{name=TriggerEventsStore, rollup=false}, Store{name=AlertHistoryStore, rollup=false}, Store{name=MetricsAggregateStore, rollup=false}] (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.KafkaStreamsManager:115)
[2017-04-04 17:22:20,607] INFO streams in state=REBALANCING (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.KafkaStreamsManager:137)
```

It does this for a long time, and then starts to spew out these exceptions, which I think might be the root cause:

```
[2017-04-04 17:29:02,732] WARN Could not create task 2_1. Will retry. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:1184)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException: task [2_1] Failed to lock the state directory: /var/lib/confluent/control-center/1/kafka-streams/_confluent-controlcenter-3-2-0-1/2_1
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.<init>(ProcessorStateManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:834)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:1207)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.retryWithBackoff(StreamThread.java:1180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:937)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$500(StreamThread.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:255)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:339)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:286)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1030)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:995)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:582)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:368)
```

Then it goes back into the rebalancing loop. It seems to give up doing that after a long time, and the Control Center never finishes starting up.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next. I tried pointing the control-center data dir config to a different directory, and the same lock exception still happens. I'm certain there is only one instance of the control center running. Nothing seems to stand out in the zookeeper logs.

If anyone has any tips for debugging this, that would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I think you also asked this question in the Confluent mailing list at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/confluent-platform/DzADuOFttNs/6AeesDItDAAJ (with answers coming in there).

Comment: Late to the party, but please don't run Control Center 3.2.0. It turned out to be quite buggy. 3.2.2, 3.3.0 and the soon-to-be-released 3.3.1 are all pretty stable. Oh, and you can run Control Center 3.3.x with brokers 0.10.2.x.